Disable FK constraint for nav property in EF Core
I am trying to map an existing database schema to EF. In the database, I have 2 parent tables that both have a one-to-many relationship with a shared child table.
In the child table, there is a single column referencing its parent ID, and another column that describes which table its parent ID is in.
There are no FK constraints set in the database.
My solution so far, is to have 2 parent entity types that both have a collection of the same child entity type.
class ParentA {
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Child>? Children {get;set;}
}

class ParentB {
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Child>? Children {get;set;}
}

class Child {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public int ParentTypeId {get;set;}
}

I do not need to reference either Parent from a Child. I just need to:

Reference a list of children from a given list of parents
Insert a child record into a SQLite in-memory database during integration tests

The EntityTypeConfiguration for ParentA (and ParentB is identical) is:
public class ParentAConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ParentA>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Child> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(esm => esm.Children)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(esm => esm.ParentId);
    }
}

When referencing the list of children from a list of a given type of parents, I can do:
var parentsWithChildren = DbContext
       .Set<ParentA>().AsNoTracking()
       .Include(parentA => parentA.Children.Where(child => child.ParentTypeId == ParentATypeId));

This generates perfectly good SQL to select only the child records that match on both the ParentId and the ParentTypeId values.
The problem occurs in my integration tests. When I insert child entities into the DbSet, I get a FK constraint violation. It seems EF Core is automatically generating an FK constraint from Child.ParentId to the ParentA table, and so when I insert a child of ParentB, with a parentId that is only valid in the ParentB table, it fails.
It is, of course, not able to take into account the parentTypeId to determine which parent table to perform the FK check against.
At runtime against a real SQL Server, there is no problem because there is no FK constraint. How do I tell EF Core to not create and check a FK constraint in this case in SQLite during integration tests?
Note that I want all other FK constraints that SQLite generates throughout the rest of my data model.
My in-memory SQLite DbContext is configured like this:
SqliteConnection connection = new($"DataSource=file:{Guid.NewGuid()}?mode=memory&cache=shared");

services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options =>
        options
            .UseSqlite(connection.ConnectionString)
            .ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalEventId.AmbientTransactionWarning))
    );

And then created during test execution with:
var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
var _dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TDbContext>();
await _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
await _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();


I think you needn't a navigation property in ef core, you can try left/inner join to query on the air?
